# "L'image que vous avez téléchargé" ou bien "L'image que vous avez téléchargée"

Tags: accord

Devons nous écrire :

```
"L'image que vous avez téléchargé"
```

ou alors devons nous écrire:

```
"L'image que vous avez téléchargée"
```

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez du coups c'est quoi ? "L'image que vous avez téléchargé" ou "L'image que vous avez téléchargée" ??

Comment: ée. Objet direct qui précède le verbe.